# How to use ROW_NUMBER() PARTITION BY()?

Tags: sql, db2

How would I implement `ROW_NUMBER() PARTITION BY()` for this dataset to get these results? I just wanted to see the current programs a person is currently enrolled in as of today.

Code:

```
SELECT
    PERSON_ID,
    PROGRAM_JOINED,
    EFFECTIVE DATE,
    PROGRAM_FINISHED_FLAG
    
FROM PROGRAM_DATE_TRACK
```

PROGRAM_DATE_TRACK

| PERSON_ID | PROGRAM_JOINED | EFFECTIVE_DATE | PROGRAM_FINISHED_FLAG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ballet | 8/1/2023 | N |
| 1 | Painting | 8/1/2023 | N |
| 1 | Ceramics | 5/30/2023 | Y |
| 2 | Figure Drawing | 8/1/2023 | N |
| 2 | Ballet | 5/30/2023 | Y |
| 2 | Ballet | 8/1/2022 | N |
| 3 | Tap | 8/1/2023 | N |
| 3 | Knitting | 1/1/2021 | Y |

What I need to see:

| PERSON_ID | PROGRAM_JOINED | EFFECTIVE_DATE | PROGRAM_FINISHED_FLAG |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ballet | 8/1/2023 | N |
| 1 | Painting | 8/1/2023 | N |
| 2 | Figure Drawing | 8/1/2023 | N |
| 3 | Tap | 8/1/2023 | N |

I have tried this, but it's including program dates that have ended. Example, Person 2 started ballet on 8/1/2022 but ended on 5/30/2023.

```
SELECT
    PERSON_ID,
    PROGRAM_JOINED,
    EFFECTIVE DATE,
    PROGRAM_FINISHED_FLAG
    ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY PERSON_ID, PROGRAM_JOINED  ORDER BY EFFECTIVE DATEE DESC) AS RANK
FROM PROGRAM_DATE_TRACK
WHERE PROGRAM_FINISHED_FLAG = 'N'
```

Results:

| PERSON_ID | PROGRAM_JOINED | EFFECTIVE_DATE | PROGRAM_FINISHED_FLAG | RANK |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Ballet | 8/1/2023 | N | 1 |
| 1 | Painting | 8/1/2023 | N | 1 |
| 2 | Figure Drawing | 8/1/2023 | N | 1 |
| 2 | Ballet | 8/1/2022 | N | 1 |
| 3 | Tap | 8/1/2023 | N | 1 |

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do

```sql
select *
from (
  select t.*,
    row_number() over(partition by person_id, program_joined
                      order by effective_date desc) as rn
  from PROGRAM_DATE_TRACK t
) x
where rn = 1 and program_finished_flag = 'N'
```

Result:

```
PERSON_ID  PROGRAM_JOINED  EFFECTIVE_DATE  PROGRAM_FINISHED_FLAG  RN 
---------- --------------- --------------- ---------------------- -- 
 1         Ballet          2023-08-01      N                      1  
 1         Painting        2023-08-01      N                      1  
 2         Figure Drawing  2023-08-01      N                      1  
 3         Tap             2023-08-01      N                      1
```

See running example at [db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/zJ0wmRt6).

Comment: This only returns 1 row for person_id 1 though.

Comment: @Stu Yep, fixed.

Answer (score 1):

You can also try using `max`

```
with cte as (
  select * , Max(PROGRAM_FINISHED_FLAG) over(partition by PERSON_ID, PROGRAM_JOINED) flag
  from t
)
select * 
from cte
where flag = 'N';
```

Comment: Works well [fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/9afK0soE).